# Creating a structural chart using XML and rendered via LaTeX

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, latex, xproc

I am trying to recreate a structural chart through XSLT with already predefined formatting i.e, their appearance defined separately. The structure is written using XML but later transformed into LaTeX code using `forest` package in directory tree style with the help of `xml2tex`, an `Xproc` library (https://github.com/transpect/xml2tex). Since they are not the main part of discussion so I am not elaborating them further.

What I do have is a sample structure in the form:

```
<structure>
  <structentry id="1" parent="0" caller="true">Root</structentry>
  <structentry id="2" parent="1" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 1 (Root)</structentry>
  <structentry id="3" parent="1" caller="false">Child 2 of ID 1 (Root)</structentry>
  <structentry id="4" parent="1" caller="false">Child 3 of ID 1 (Root)</structentry>
  <structentry id="5" parent="4" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 4</structentry>
  <structentry id="6" parent="5" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 5</structentry>
</structure>
```

Ideally the output should be in the form:

```
[{Root},fill=white[{Child 1 of ID 1 (Root)}][{Child 2 of ID 1 (Root)}][{Child 3 of ID 1 (Root)}[{Child 1 of ID 4}[{Child 1 of ID 5}]]]]
```

Or for readability' sake:

```
[{Root},fill=white
  [{Child 1 of ID 1 (Root)}]
  [{Child 2 of ID 1 (Root)}]
  [{Child 3 of ID 1 (Root)}
    [{Child 1 of ID 4}
      [{Child 1 of ID 5}]
    ]
  ]
]
```

which then visually looks like this:

[image: Sample structure]

Hence, I am trying to put nodes under their parents through their matching ids. That is, any node having `parent='1'` should be child of node having `id='1'`.

I have the following transformation which uses 'dbk' (DocBook) namespaces for defining nodes in the input XML. Since I am very new in XML, XSLT and XPath, I can't help but remain stuck here after `xsl:template match="dbk:structentry"`. If any additional information is required I will gladly update them.

```
  <template context="dbk:structure">
    <text>\begin{center}&#xa;</text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dbk:caption"/>
    <text>\rule[5pt]{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}&#xa;</text>
    <text>&#xa;\begin{forest}</text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dbk:structentry"/>
    <text>\end{forest}</text>
    <text>&#xa;\end{center}</text>
  </template>

  <xsl:template match="dbk:caption">
    \textbf{<xsl:value-of select="."/>}&#xa;
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dbk:structentry">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@parent eq '0' and @caller eq 'true'">
      [{<xsl:value-of select="."/>},fill=white<xsl:apply-templates select="@parent eq '1'">]
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      [{<xsl:value-of select="."/>}]
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE**

A new problem is how can I differentiate one root entry of a chart from the root entry of another chart? Here's an example of 2 structures:

Structure 1:

```
<structure>
  <structentry id="1" parent="0" caller="true">Root 1</structentry>
  <structentry id="2" parent="1" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 1 (Root 1)</structentry>
  <structentry id="3" parent="1" caller="false">Child 2 of ID 1 (Root 1)</structentry>
  <structentry id="4" parent="1" caller="false">Child 3 of ID 1 (Root 1)</structentry>
  <structentry id="5" parent="4" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 4</structentry>
  <structentry id="6" parent="5" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 5</structentry>
</structure>
```

Structure 2:

```
<structure>
  <structentry id="7" parent="0" caller="true">Root 2</structentry>
  <structentry id="8" parent="7" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 7 (Root 2)</structentry>
  <structentry id="9" parent="7" caller="false">Child 2 of ID 7 (Root 2)</structentry>
  <structentry id="10" parent="7" caller="false">Child 3 of ID 7 (Root 2)</structentry>
  <structentry id="11" parent="10" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 10</structentry>
  <structentry id="12" parent="11" caller="false">Child 1 of ID 11</structentry>
</structure>
```

Comment: I have posted an answer - but in general, a question like this should be closed.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Not being able to help oneself from helping isn't such a bad thing.  Congratulations on 100K.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks. See you soon on this side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not very difficult to write an XSLT stylesheet that will produce the result you show:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="structentry" use="@parent" />

<xsl:template match="/structure">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', 0)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="structentry">
    <xsl:text>[{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="@parent=0">,fill=white</xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @id)"/>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whether that fits in your overall scheme is hard for me to tell.

---

### Added:

If your XML document has multiple `structure` elements, but the ids are unique document-wide, you can simply change the instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', 0)"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', 0, .)"/>
```

to limit the scope of the key to the current `structure` element. This is assuming your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher. In XSLT 1.0 you would need to use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="structentry[@parent=0]"/>
```

which is less efficient, since the `parent` values have already been indexed.

---

And of course you need to have:

```
<xsl:template match="structure">
```

without the leading `/`.

Comment: Your solution worked great! The only change I needed to make is `match="structentry"` to `match="dbk:structentry"` (since I mentioned I was using `dbk` namespace for input) and `key('child', 0)` to `key('child', '0')`. Also I forgot to mention that whoever has `caller="true"` will have `fill=white`. I made that change anyway and all looks perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @michael.hor257k there does seem to be a conflict with one structural chart and another when they share the same ids. Assuming all the entries have different ids, how do I actually different the first entries (the root nodes) of every structural chart?

Comment: The answer depends on the version of XSLT that your processor supports.

Comment: P.S. Please edit your question and show an example of XML with 2 structures.

Comment: I think my processor supports upto version 2.0? I checked many `xsl` files having this version

Comment: See here how to find out for sure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: OK I updated on your request

Comment: Hmm the vendor is returned as `Saxonica` while the version is `3.0`

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks again!